# Python inheritance. Field variable doesn't exist?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have an employee class that is the superclass of a production worker class. There is an issue where an instance of a production worker does not seem to recognize the existence of one of the defined fields of its superclass (Employee)

Here is the error message plus what I inputted into the program

```
Please enter the employee's number: 9987
Please enter the employee's name: Leo
Please enter the employee's shift number (1 for day shift 2 for night shift): 2
Please enter the employee's hourly pay rate: 18.67
-------------------
Here is some information about your employee
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jdoodle.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "jdoodle.py", line 40, in main
    print("Here is their employee number: " + str(person.getEmpNum()))
  File "jdoodle.py", line 12, in getEmpNum
    return __empNum
NameError: name '_Employee__empNum' is not defined
```

Here are the class definitions

```
class Employee:
    def setName(self, name):
        self.__empName = name

    def setEmpNum(self, empNum):
        self.__empNum = empNum

    def getName(self):
        return __empName

    def getEmpNum(self):
        return __empNum
```

```
class ProductionWorker(Employee):
    def setShiftNum(self, num):
        self.__shiftNum = num

    def setPayRate(self, payrate):
        self.__payrate = payrate

    def getShiftNum(self):
        return __shiftNum

    def getPayRate(self):
        return __payrate
```

Here is the main method

```
def main():   
    person = ProductionWorker()
    empNum = int(input("Please enter the employee's number: "))
    empName = input("Please enter the employee's name: ")
    shiftNum = int(input("Please enter the employee's shift number (1 for day shift 2 for night shift): "))
    payrate = float(input("Please enter the employee's hourly pay rate: "))
    person.setName(empName)
    person.setEmpNum(empNum)
    person.setShiftNum(shiftNum)
    person.setPayRate(payrate)

    print("-------------------")
    print("Here is some information about your employee")
    print("Here is their employee number: " + str(person.getEmpNum()))
    print("Here is their name: " + person.getName())
    print("Here is their payrate: " + str(person.getPayRate()))
    print("Here is their shift number: " + str(person.getShiftNum()))
    print("-------------------")
```

Comment: You need to be specific in Python: `return self.__empNum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assigned to your class in `setEmpNum` but are not retrieving the class variable on the call to `getEmpNum`.

You will want your getter to reference the class attribute as well:

```py
def getEmpNum(self):
    return self.__empNum
```

Comment: ahh. So would the reference I made only be applicable to static variables?

Comment: yes- say you wanted a function to get total pay for the employee you could create a function, pass in hours worked, and assign `total_pay = hours * self.__payrate`, then return `total_pay`